# Taking the limit of an integral expression

Tags: limits

Hi guys I was doing the following question:-

let a,b ∈ $\mathbb{R}$ with a < b show the following

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int^a_b\frac{((b-a){e^x}^2)}{(b-a)n^2{e^x}^2+b^2} dx = 0 $$

so i started taking the lim as $\lim{n\to \infty}$ which gives the following:-

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{((b-a){e^x}^2)}{(b-a)n^2{e^x}^2+b^2}  $$

Since i am trying to evaluate the limit I decided to remove the top expression since its a constant and ended up getting

$$(b-a){e^x}^2\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{(b-a)n^2{e^x}^2+b^2}  $$

Now looking at the denominator expression can i directly substitute n as infinity

therefore this gives the following:-

$$(b-a){e^x}^2\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{(b-a)(\infty)^2{e^x}^2+b^2}  $$

Can i take this expression to be $\frac{1}{\infty} = 0 $

hence i get the following $$(b-a){e^x}^2(0) = 0 $$

Therefore when i go to the next part of the question to evaluate the integral well = 0 since the above shows that when the limit is evaluated f(x) = 0. I am not sure if i evaluated this question correctly when looking at the limit aspect and so hoping so one can confirm this for me.

Comment: You LaTeX says the oddly formatted exponentials are $(\mathrm{e}^x)^2$, not $\mathrm{e}^{x^2}$.  Are you sure that is correct?

Comment: yes thats correct what i typed is what the question has in it

Comment: I ask because the usual way to write $(\mathrm{e}^x)^2$ is "$\mathrm{e}^{2x}$".

Comment: yeah i understand but the question has it as i typed it so yeah thats the correct notation that i provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need, for example, Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem to guarantee the swiping of the integral with the limit to move on.

Or you can do it in the following way, because the integrand has no singularity:
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{(b-a)e^{x^{2}}}{(b-a)n^{2}e^{x^{2}}+b^{2}}\leq\dfrac{(b-a)e^{b^{2}}}{(b-a)n^{2}e^{a^{2}}+b^{2}}\leq\dfrac{(b-a)e^{b^{2}}}{(b-a)n^{2}e^{a^{2}}}=\dfrac{e^{b^{2}}}{e^{a^{2}}}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}.
\end{align*}
Taking integral both sides, the right sided is just $(b-a)\dfrac{e^{b^{2}}}{e^{a^{2}}}\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}$ and this goes to zero, now you use Squeeze Theorem to conclude that the integral also goes to zero.

Comment: I was not introduced to Lebesgue Dominated convergence so thats why i did it like that.

Comment: Anyway, the second one uses elementary analysis, no hard theorem anyway.

Comment: so based on my answer is that completely inaccurate or incorrect rather based on my approach of the limit to then go onto to the integral?

Comment: Actually yours is correct, just without more reasoning to support. You implicitly swiped the integral and the limit, in this case, it goes through.

Comment: OP seems to have clarified in comments that the integrand you use is not OP's integrand.

Comment: oh ok based on the question i evaluated the limit but didnot show how the integral goes to zero yeah i understand i just used the fact based on the limit i understand. Ill look into lebesgue dominated convergence to see how the integral is evaluated using user284331 answer.

Comment: This question becomes trivial if you just use the fact that $b^{2} \geq 0$.

Comment: the question did say b > a

Comment: Actually you can write $(b-a)e^{x^{2}}/((b-a)n^{2}e^{x^{2}}+b^{2})\leq (b-a)e^{x^{2}}/(b-a)e^{x^{2}}n^{2}=1/n^{2}$.

Comment: ok thanks for the help and the notation great help.

Answer (score -1):

$0$ is  the correct limit you can get it from the fact that the integrand lies between $0$ and $\frac 1 {n^{2}}$ because $b^{2} \geq 0$. Hence the integral itself lies between  $0$ and  $\frac {b-a} {n^{2}}$. You don't have to evaluate the integral or apply a theorem like DCT.

Comment: i was considering this $$(b-a){e^x}^2\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{(b-a)n^2{e^x}^2+b^2} \leq \frac{1}{n^2}  $$ would be accurate to say or is that what your saying ? Oh btw my evaluation of the expression was done properly?